# Unique tuples in R with rle

Tags: r, unique

How to unique (rle unique) tuples in a df like this

```
structure(c("M01", "M01", "M01", "M01", "M01", "M02", "M02", 
"M02", "M02", "M03", "M03", "F04", "F04", "F02", "F02", "F04", 
"F10", "F10", NA, "F10", "F01", "F01"), .Dim = c(11L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("a", "b")))

> sample
      a     b    
 [1,] "M01" "F04"
 [2,] "M01" "F04"
 [3,] "M01" "F02"
 [4,] "M01" "F02"
 [5,] "M01" "F04"
 [6,] "M02" "F10"
 [7,] "M02" "F10"
 [8,] "M02" NA   
 [9,] "M02" "F10"
[10,] "M03" "F01"
[11,] "M03" "F01"
```

to get this :

```
structure(c("M01", "M01", "M01", "M02", "M02", "M03", "F04", 
"F02", "F04", "F10", "F10", "F01"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("d", "c")))
> output
     d     c    
[1,] "M01" "F04"
[2,] "M01" "F02"
[3,] "M01" "F04"
[4,] "M02" "F10"
[5,] "M02" "F10"
[6,] "M03" "F01"
```

So the idea is to get a df with tuples, but unique based on row and based only on previous element, so :
    unique(sample)
Doesn't give what I need. Could rle be run on this df in a way to consider tuples, and to keep df as output ? Is there a better approach ?

```
rle(sample[,2]$values)
```

gives wanted results but obviously I loose valuable info of column 1.

Comment: The logic behind how you get your desired output makes absolutely no sense to me. You're probably going to have to explain that better.

Comment: I think he just wants rows that are not duplicates of the row directly above it.

Comment: Ok, sorry I wasn't clear. I edited the question. The unique part should be run on rows and as Senor O pointed, only on row directly above it.

Comment: Ok. Frankly, I'd just allocate a indicator vector of the right length, fill it in a for loop, subset your matrix and move on, rather than try to think of something more clever.

Comment: @Chargaff, have you had a look at my answer yet?

Comment: @Arun, yes, works flawlessly on my actual dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
# dd is the matrix structure you posted in the question
dd <- as.data.frame(dd)                     ## convert to data.frame
dd[] <- lapply(dd, as.character)            ## change columns to character
na.omit(dd[cumsum(rle(dd$b)$lengths), ])    ## get indices by cumsum'ing rle-lengths 
                                            ## wrap with na.omit to remove NA rows
#      a   b
# 2  M01 F04
# 4  M01 F02
# 5  M01 F04
# 7  M02 F10
# 9  M02 F10
# 11 M03 F01
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining your answer. Cumsum'ing is nice !